# Gratis program to use my iPad as a second monitor for my Windows computer

Tags: windows, gratis, ipad-app, multi-monitor

I am looking for a gratis program that can allow me to use my iPad as a second monitor for my computer (Microsoft Windows).

I'm aware of:

- [Duet Display](https://www.duetdisplay.com/): costs between 10 USD for the basic version and 20 USD for the "pro" version. Received 17.4k ratings, and the average rating is 4.3/5.
- [Air Display](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/air-display-3/id967502646?ign-mpt=uo%3D4): costs around 10 USD and ratings aren't positive.
- [iDisplay](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/idisplay/id363500805?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4): costs around 15 USD and ratings aren't positive.
- [Splashtop](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/splashtop-extended-wireless/id765801888?mt=8&at=1010loXs&ct=100886): costs around 5 USD and ratings aren't positive.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/TWK7Om

Answer (score 1):

You can use [spacedesk](https://spacedesk.net/):

- gratis for personal use
- requires the computer and the iPad to be in the same network (e.g., same Wi-Fi network)
- also works for Android
- good ratings on Play store and iOS App store but not many ratings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Splashtop Wired XDisplay HD – Extend & Mirror 4+](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/splashtop-wired-xdisplay-hd-extend-mirror/id1029826353):

- gratis but might become non-gratis in the future ("**** LIMITED TIME Launch Special (Regular Price: $19.99 USD)" according to the iOS App store)
- works with macOS and Microsoft Windows
- iOS App store ratings: 3.8/5 (186 Ratings)